# fadein a DIV when another DIV is clicked then fadeout when DIV is clicked again

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, fadeout

I have a sliding panel on my page which brings out the navigation (www.helloarchie.blue). When the panel slides out, I'd like to fade in the content inside slowly, then fadeout the content when the user clicks the icon to close the panel. How would I do that?

CSS: (div I want to fadein/out)

```
.sb-slidebar nav { text-align: left; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sb-slidebar sb-right sb-style-push sb-active">

<nav>
 <div class="cl-effect-5 blah">
 <a href="http://helloarchie.blue/"><span data-hover="Home">Home</span></a><br />
<a href="http://helloarchie.blue/about"><span data-hover="About">About</span></a><br />
<a href="http://helloarchie.blue/archives"><span data-hover="Archives">Archives</span></a><br />
<a href="http://helloarchie.blue/design"><span data-hover="Services">Services</span></a><br />
<a href="http://helloarchie.blue/contact-me" title="Contact Kaye at Hello Archie"><span data-hover="Contact me">Contact me</span></a><br />

</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

HTML (this is the icon I want the user to click to open the panel and fadein/out the content)

```
<div class="sb-toggle-right button-square menu">

  <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="button2">
  <span class="menu-bar bar1"></span>
  <span class="menu-bar bar2"></span>
  <span class="menu-bar bar3"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Please also provide the relevant JavaScript, and make a stack snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's `.fadeToggle()`, as in the example below. See the documentation for `.fadeToggle()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#click-me').on('click', function() {
    $('#fade-me').fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#fade-me {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
#click-me {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fade-me"></div>
<div id="click-me">Toggle Fade</div>
```

So, applying to your code sample, you would want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sb-toggle-right').on('click', function() {
        $('.sb-slidebar').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't know where to start so I hadn't tried anything yet! The above works, but it fades the DIV out when the user first clicks, whereas I need the content to fadein on the first click? I tried adding an opacity of 1 to the fade-me div, but didn't work.

Comment: Just updated the answer. You just need to add `display: none` in your css for the div that you are fading, then it will not be shown until the other div is clicked.

Comment: Hmm, it stops working as soon as I add display: none; to the DIV. How strange. I thought it might be that it's fading in too fast but I've tried to slow it down and it still isn't working. :(

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the classname you have used on div in question it looks like you're using a plugin to handle the sliding in/out of the panel? Without seeing the javascript you're using it's difficult to say exactly what you could do but I'd have thought if you can access the plugin's documentation you may be able to locate methods used to run functions at the beginning and end of the animation/slide. In these methods I would add/remove a classname of my own which handle the fade in and out of the div. It would look somehting like this:

Javascript:

```
onSlideStart: function() {
        $(this).removeClass('fade-me-in');
},
onSlideEnd: function() {
        $(this).addClass('fade-me-in');
}
```

CSS

```
div {
    opacity: 0;
}

div.fade-me-in {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
```

I hope that helps, if not, post the javascript you're using and I may be able to help further.